# How to style the active component to its hover state in react multi carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, react-multi-carousel

Ive installed react multi carousel from here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel.
Here's my component `toolsCardCarousel.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
import ToolsCard from '../ToolsCard/toolsCard';
import CustomDots from './customDots';

function ToolsCardCarousel() {
    const responsive = {
        desktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1920 },
          items: 5,
        //   partialVisibilityGutter: 40,
        },
        tablet: {
          breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
          items: 2,
        //   partialVisibilityGutter: 40,
        },
        mobile: {
          breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
          items: 1,
        //   partialVisibilityGutter: 40,
        }
      };
    return (
        <div>
            <Carousel
                autoPlay={false}
                swipeable={true}
                draggable={true}
                showDots={true}
                customDot={<CustomDots/>}
                responsive={responsive}
                infinite
                partialVisbile
                focusOnSelect={true}
            >
                <ToolsCard></ToolsCard>
                <ToolsCard></ToolsCard>
                <ToolsCard></ToolsCard>
                <ToolsCard></ToolsCard>
            </Carousel>;
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default ToolsCardCarousel
```

Here's `toolsCard.js`

```
import React from "react";
import PrimaryButton from "../Buttons/primaryButton";
import '../ToolsCard/toolsCard.scss'
import Images from "../../components/Images";
function ToolsCard(props) {
  const backgroundimage = {
      backgroundImage: 'url('+Images.bg7+')',
      backgroundSize:'cover'
  };
  return (
    <div className="toolcard-container">
      <div className="toolcard-container-bg" style={backgroundimage}>
        <div className="toolcard-container-bg-overlay"></div>
      </div>
        <div className="toolcard-container-logo">
          <img src={Images.blender} alt="blender logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="toolcard-container-heading">
          <h2>After Effects</h2>
        </div>
      <div className="toolcard-container-content">
        <div className="toolcard-container-content-body">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed arcu tortor, venenatis non massa vel, faucibus porta erat. Mauris auctor et urna id finibus. Mauris et hendrerit tortor, sit amet tincidunt justo. 
          </p>
        </div>
          <div className="toolcard-container-content-button">
            <PrimaryButton type="default" text="Know More" />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToolsCard;
```

and heres how i want to trigger the hover effect in `toolsCard.scss` (*some codes have been left out as they arent as necessary to solving the problem)*

```
& .active, &:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
  }
  & .active, &:hover &-bg{
    transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
    filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px) brightness(1.1);

  }
  & .active, &:hover &-logo{
    transform:  scale(0.8);
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(71%) sepia(81%) saturate(1982%) hue-rotate(174deg) brightness(88%) contrast(97%);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;

  }
  & .active, &:hover &-heading{
    transform:scale(1.2);
    color: $blue;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
  & .active, &:hover &-content{
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

and here's `customDots.js` if anyone wants to know

```
import React from 'react'

const CustomDots = ({ onClick, active, index, carouselState }) => {
    const { currentSlide } = carouselState;
    return (
      <li style={{ background: active ? "grey" : "initial" }}>
        <button
          style={{ background: active ? "grey" : "initial" }}
          onClick={() => onClick()}
        />
      </li>
    );
  };

export default CustomDots
```

I want to set the ***active*** class for the ***toolcard-container*** div inside the **ToolsCard** component, from `toolsCardCarousel.js` depending on whichever element is on focus or active.
I've thought about ways to do it with props but i dont know what to pass as my props!
The component structure is like this-
ToolCardCarousel
|
|____ ToolsCard
|
|____   ToolsCard(active)
|
|____ ToolsCard
|
|____ ToolsCard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to add class .active to the div inside the toolcard component from inside the carousel component!